# __init_subclass__ error while intercepting contextMenuEvent() in QLineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm testing some of the pyqt widgets and their methods but I've been stuck with the problem when I was creating a subclass which inherits the QLineEdit class in order to create context menu when right mouse button is clicked. This class has the main window as a parent.

Running of this code gives this output:

```
TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
```

I tried to add **kwargs as a perameter of __ init_subclass__ method but actually I don't know what's the point of it.

Here is some code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.resize(300, 120)
        self.setWindowTitle('Testing')

        self.edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.edit.createStandardContextMenu()

        self.box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.box.addWidget(self.edit)

class ConetextMenu(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, parent = Window):
    def __init_subclass__(self, parent = Window, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QLineEdit.__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, ev):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to be able to create custom context menu to QLineEdit and handle this problem with subclass.

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use __init_subclass__ to inherit from QLineEdit, you also try to go to Window as a parent and this is not possible since the QLineEdit parent must be a QWidget object, not a QWidget class.

The following is an example of how you should do it:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = self.createStandardContextMenu()
        menu.addSeparator()
        foo_action = menu.addAction("Foo")
        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action == foo_action:
            print("foo")


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(300, 120)
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing")

        self.edit = LineEdit()

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(self.edit)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```